# Unexpected route on a flight from USA to Europe

Tags: air-travel, great-circle-route

I fly often between London and east coast USA (usually New York or Boston) - and every single time up until now the flight would go along the [great circle route](https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/flight-paths-and-great-circles-or-why-you-flew-over-greenland/).

I flew yesterday from Boston to London - and to my mild surprise the flight path went a lot further south - almost along the parallel. I can't get the full flight radar replay (I guess you need a paid membership for that), but here is a picture I took of the inflight progress display a couple of hours into the flight.

[image]

This was flight VS158 (actually renamed to VS1158 due to change of destination airport).

Why would such an unusual path be chosen?  I understand that it's unlikely we'd know the exact reasoning for this particular flight, so I'm wondering how and why decisions to route this way are made.

Edited to add: the flight was on 6 August 2019.

Comment: Why unexpected? On my East-bound flights, this is the most normal track. Just on west-bound flight one *usually* flight much more on North.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Aviation.SE]; most passengers don't notice such things, so long as they arrive on time.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi "unexpected" to me, because this is the first time I saw this in my 50+ flights from BOS to LON.

Comment: Flightradar24 will give you full replays of everything in the last week, for free. Your flight is [here](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/vs158#219678cb).

Comment: You might want to save the images of recent flight paths for future reference here.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The specific answer concerning your flight is that yesterday there were abnormally fast westerly winds over the mid-north-Atlantic, which many eastbound flights took advantage of.

You can still see them, as of the time of this edit, here:

https://www.ventusky.com/?p=43.5;-32.4;3&l=temperature-200hpa

(shown are winds at a pressure altitude of 12000m, approximately the cruising altitude of a plane)

Comment: Are "Westerly" winds supposed to blow from west to east?
Also a timestamped link: https://www.ventusky.com/?p=43.0;-49.9;3&l=wind-200hpa&t=20190807/0000

Comment: @TejasKale: [Yes, they are.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/westerly)

Answer (score 10):

In short, your flight followed what is known as a "North Atlantic Track".

These are paths in the air above the North Atlantic which are used by air traffic control to effectively manage aircraft separation in the North Atlantic (where there are lots of planes and little radar coverage). Planes' entry into these tracks is managed for safety reasons and individualised flight plans are avoided.

The specifics of where these tracks are is determined by factors such as winds/jet-stream among many other considerations. There are also multiple tracks in operation at a time, meaning that a BOS-LHR flight will likely be on a different one than ATL-MAD (for example).

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Atlantic_Tracks) on this is pretty good!

Comment: Ah! Very interesting. I've travelled london to/from boston over a hundred times of the last 10 years - and this was the first time we didn't go great circle route.

Comment: @AleksG if you look at it in detail you'll find that the tracks approximate a great circle route but do not follow it exactly.  When the winds are strong, the benefit of diverging from the great circle is relatively more pronounced.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I see. I didn't give it much thought yesterday, but we were flying at over 600 knots most of the way.

Comment: @AleksG air speed or ground speed?  The air speed will almost always be about the same, which is why airlines will seek to avoid headwinds when flying west and to catch tailwinds when flying east.

Comment: @phoog Both actually. The flight completed very fast.  It left on schedule and arrived about 40 minutes ahead of schedule.

Comment: @AleksG by "or" I meant only to account for the fact that a single plane cannot simultaneously fly both east and west.  There are not generally tailwinds for westbound planes at these latitudes, nor headwinds for eastbound planes; the air moves from west to east pretty much continuously.  This is factored into the schedule (along with additional padding, usually, for unanticipated delays, so arriving ahead of schedule is to be expected when everything goes smoothly).

Comment: @phoog It would definitely be groundspeed, not airspeed. No airliners fly at 600 KIAS. That would be supersonic at that altitude. Even 600 knots true airspeed would be supersonic above around FL250. From FL350 up through the Tropopause, Mach 1 is around 573 knots true airspeed.

Comment: @reirab I suffer from a lack of intuition about the conversion factor, apparently. In that case, the difference between the cruising speed of an airliner (somewhat less than 500 knots) and the reported ground speed makes the ground speed seem very unlikely to me.  Winds do not generally flow from east to west at speeds of over 100 knots as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @reirab I just reread the question and saw that I misinterpreted the direction of travel.  This explains my confusion!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen many times when flying from China to America.  The thing is, airplanes don't actually care how far away the destination is, but rather they care about the flying time.  When you are flying against the wind (as you generally are when heading west in the northern hemisphere) your best bet is the shortest route, hence flights heading west take the great circle route unless there is a political reason to do otherwise.  (I've seen plenty of small zigs to avoid entering airspace and I've once seen a zig of hundreds of miles when they didn't want to fly anywhere near North Korea.)

However, when heading with the wind you can often find it is more advantageous to take the path with the most wind than to take the shortest path.  I've seen a 200 mph tailwind.